# What term describes a function with finite 'humps' that does not continue indefinitely?

Tags: functions, terminology

I'm looking for a term that captures the essence of a relation/function that exhibits a series of 'humps'. The typical word I would use is 'oscillatory', but this implies a sort of endless continuation of the peaks and troughs, which is not applicable in my case. My relation/function only has these features over a specific interval and does not exhibit this behavior indefinitely.

Here is a sample figure for reference:

[image: figure with humps]

The 'humps' are not periodic and do not persist indefinitely. Each 'hump' does not necessarily lead to a local maximum or minima.

Is there a more accurate word than 'oscillatory' to describe this behavior? Or is 'oscillatory' still the best choice despite the finite nature of the pattern?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: The term *oscillatory* does not imply a relation or function oscillates indefinitely. If you want to emphasize that it does *not* oscillate indefinitely but instead oscillates over a finite interval, then simply say that. Also, you seem to be using the terms "relation" and "function" interchangeably, and it's worth noting they are not the same. A function is a relation satisifying very specific criteria (that is, every element in the domain is mapped to exactly one element in the codomain).

Comment: I'd call it an implicit function over a finite interval

Comment: I don't think there are any standard (or even relatively unknown) terms for this, but maybe you could refer to the points of locally maximum curvature as "bend points".

Comment: What do you thing of the word 'undulations/undulatory'?

Answer (score 0):

If instead of concentrating on the "top of each hump", we consider breaking your curve into sections, where each section consists of one "hump", then the points that separate the sections

[image: image of same curve with inflection points added]

are "[inflection points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point)".

So you could describe your curve as "having only a finite number of inflection points". You could also add "after which the curvature doesn't change direction", if you wanted to describe the non-oscillating parts.

It would probably also be fine to say "it oscillates over a bounded interval, and then [calms down] ....". However, the terms "oscillate" and "calm down" are kind of hand-wavy and not precisely defined. So you might want to start with that description, but add the "inflection point" description to be rigorous.